# Angular Paypal Checkout 2.0 get userdetails after payment

Tags: angular, paypal

i have created a app which sells some stuff. For my payment i'm using paypal. To create the invoice i have to get user information like the name or its adress. Paypal is storing those information from every user. So how can i access those details from my angular app directly?. Here is my code:

```
  paypal
  .Buttons({
    createOrder: (data, actions) => {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [
          {
            description: this.data.description,
            amount: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: this.data.price
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    },
    onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.paidFor = true;
      const couponId = this.makeid(20);
      this.saveInUserProfile(couponId);

    },
    onError: err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
  .render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
```

I have already checked if i can see any user specific data, but the only thing i'm receiving in my onApprove is the payer Id (maybe i can get the data from this id)

This is the data object:

```
{orderID: "0LL76988V8521984L", payerID: "34BXT6HM769JU", paymentID: 
 "", billingToken: null, facilitatorAccessToken: 
 "A21AAEz6q1xm2Sd7pMGfEhet5o8MNgJq4G6qhauV8Yj_iUKAgUwyGL- 
 XGncloYSFLXmFbjlIS2HZ3rRv0gLTQ5YHm8bL0lnoQ"}
 billingToken: null
 facilitatorAccessToken: 
 "A21AAEz6q1xm2Sd7pMGfEhet5o8MNgJq4G6qhauV8Yj_iUKAgUwyGL- 
  XGncloYSFLXmFbjlIS2HZ3rRv0gLTQ5YHm8bL0lnoQ"
  orderID: "0LL76988V8521984L"
  payerID: "34BXT6HM769JU"
  paymentID: ""
  __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look further into `console.log(data)` , there is plenty of information in the sub objects